# Ease of use of SMD Led components

Tags: led, soldering, surface-mount

I was thinking about inserting some lights in postcards. But classic leds would increase the thickness too much.

Is it easy enough to use this kind of component for a simple circuit(just one or two leds and a battery)? Is it in reach for a soldering beginner?
Would it work without a stable PCB?

---

<sub>I am asking about your opinion on feasability; not especially how to do it. The answers would lead me to go deeper in this way or go for flat "classic" leds.</sub>

---

Inspiration: http://www.blackbookgallery.com/prints/hari-deepti/

Comment: its feasible, its not very resistant though.. even LED strips which are "made to be" flexible fail under fatigue..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Conductive ink works wonders for this. A 0805 led and some conductive ink, flexing somewhat:

[image]

And a more complex one:

[image]

Bonus. No traditional soldering needed. The Ink is both glue and conductor.

The issue you may find is that a post office automatic sorter may bend the post card too much, or get caught on the led.

***The biggest issue though, would be the power source.*** Any reasonable coin cell battery may be too thick, or not bend enough. And attaching it may not be easy.

Comment: Perfect! Why did I forget this solution?! Thank you for passing by. Having a 2mm bulge in one corner would be reasonable. The bend ing could hopefully be limited enough when package in a thick paper enveloppe.